# How can I write a css that inherits the external css (html-email)?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I need to write a html email. Everything seems to be quite OK, but the code looks messy.

I have the following html table:

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;border: 1px solid #cccccc" class="responsive-table100">
```

Please focus on class "responsive-table100". This class is not written by me, it comes from somewhere I don't know. I just only know with this class, I can make a responsive table. It seems to come from media css.

```
@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
        table[class="responsive-table100"] {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:500px) {
        *[class="mobile-width-20"] {
            width: 20px !important;
        }
    }
```

I tried to make the code shorter as follow:

```
.container-table {
        border: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width:600px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        text-align: center;
        margin:0px auto;
    }

<table class="container-table responsive-table100">
```

With the above code, only .container-table css is applied, the responsive-table100 is not. How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: "it comes from somewhere I don't know" — Since you say it doesn't apply, it looks like it doesn't come from anywhere at all.

Comment: It is highly recommended to always use inline styles in mailings

Comment: Could you make  JSFiddle? Do you have `.responsive-table100` code?

Comment: it comes from media css (or media query source)

Comment: @chipbk10 the media CSS of what? *Your* media CSS? A specific browser's media CSS? A specific email client's CSS?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: actually I don't know, I found this template, in which I cannot find out where the class .responsive-table100 is. There is no reference to this class.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a guide.. to better css development..

If you are going for HTML5 documents (What is definitely recommended.)
use of attributes like `bgcolor` are not supported.

Now the basic:

```css
.iCALLyou {
  /* this is only for elements with class iCallyou*/
  background-color: red;
}
.YOUcallMe {
  /* this is only for elements with class YOUcallMe*/
  color: green;
}
/* if you give an element a class or more (you seprate with <space>) he will look for CSS code that targets the class  */
```

```html
<table class="iCALLyou YOUcallMe">

  <tr>
    <td>RUNNNN</td>
  </tr>

</table>


<table class="YOUcallMe">

  <tr>
    <td>RUNNNN NOW</td>
  </tr>

</table>


<table class="iCALLyou">

  <tr>
    <td>RUNNNN FAR AWAY</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

**So if you take the prev example and edit it a little:**

```css
.iCALLyou {
  /* this is only for elements with class iCallyou*/
  background-color: red;
}
.YOUcallMe {
  /* this is only for elements with class YOUcallMe*/
  color: green;
}
/* if you give an element a class or more (you seprate with <space>) he will look for CSS code that targets the class  */

.borderLittle {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.borderFat {
  border: 9px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="iCALLyou YOUcallMe">

  <tr>
    <td>RUNNNN</td>
  </tr>

</table>


<table class="YOUcallMe">

  <tr>
    <td>RUNNNN NOW</td>
  </tr>

</table>


<table class="iCALLyou borderLittle borderFat">

  <tr>
    <td>RUNNNN FAR AWAY (the classes with border that is last defined will be shown)</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

So, to have the responsive-100 class in your element you need to define it inside the css-stylesheet.

but.. in mails inline-styling is better `<element style="background-color: pink"></element>`.

Comment: Thank you for all the code and guide.

Comment: ^Feel free to @tag me with any question :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer: your attribute selector isn't quite right in the CSS.

```
table[class="responsive-table100"]
```

This will match a table where the class **equals** "responsive-table100". (And only that.)

```
table[class~="responsive-table100"]
```

This (with the **~=** ) will match a table where the class **contains** "responsive-table100". Generally speaking when programming emails I will use ~= in most all my attribute selectors.

---

**Bonus:** if you want it to work in Gmail, use the **summary** attribute instead of the **class** attribute for class names, because Gmail strips classes and IDs out of your HTML code.

CSS:

```
table[summary~="responsive-table100"]
```

HTML:

```
<table summary="responsive-table100">
```